# Spring Boot logging to file in Windows PC with application.yml

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging

I have searched the internet for some hours now.
I cannot find this trivial thing.
I am using a Windows PC.
I am using Spring boot and using all the defaults.
I want to log to a file and am using YAML application format.
My `application.yml`is in `src/main/resources`.
Its contents are exactly those:

```
spring:
  logging:
    file: logs/app.log
    pattern:
      console: "%d [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"
      file: "%d [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"
    level:
      com.m2evorah: DEBUG
      org.springframework: DEBUG
      org.hibernate: DEBUG
```

I can see the logging normally in console within Eclipse IDE, but then when I go and search my PC for an `app.log` file, I cannot find it. So, even if it goes according to classpath etc, I should still be able to see it in my searches. What is wrong with my yml file?

Answer (score 7):

Wow! I finally got it working. The successful `application.yml` for me was this:

```
logging:
  file.name: logs/app.log
  pattern:
    console: "%d [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"
    file: "%d [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"
  level:
    com.m2evorah: DEBUG
    org.springframework: DEBUG
    org.hibernate: DEBUG
```

Notice the `file.name` was used.

Answer (score 2):

`logging.file` property is not under `spring` property tree.

In your case path is defined as `spring.logging.file`.

Yaml should look like this:

```
logging:
  file.name: logs/app.log
  pattern:
    console: "%d [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"
    file: "%d [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"
  level:
    com.m2evorah: DEBUG
    org.springframework: DEBUG
    org.hibernate: DEBUG
```

**EDIT:**

Instead of `logging.file` property `logging.file.name` should be used

Comment: Thanks! How I misplaced this thing. I also checked from other sources in the internet and its true that logging should be on the root level in the Yaml file. Also in Eclipse iDE,  a warning when editing the Yaml file got away! Unfortunately, I still cannot find the file in my searches. :( Is there anything else I might have done wrong? To be even more specific, I have also some Spring configuration in my file. I try to repost the complete renewed file for completeness, but I cannot insert it nicely as code. ```does not work...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting the logging configuration in `application.yml` create `log4j.properties/log4j.yml` file in the same `src/main/resources` folder and put the below configurations

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file

# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.datePattern='_'yyyy-MM-dd'.log'

log4j.appender.file.File=logs/Facts.log

log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=timestamp=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} | level=%-5p | source=%c{1}:%L | logMessage=%m%n
```

**Note:** logs folder will be created in your project which contains Facts.log file and every day new log files will be generated and keep track of your project on daily basis

Just place below code in your specific class where you want to apply the logger

```
Logger logger = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(<classname>.class);
```